# flutter - realtime stream data from REST API

Tags: flutter, dart

I am retrieving data from a REST API using a stream, but when the data updates in the database the stream does not refresh the data in the app.

```
StreamController _productsController = new StreamController();
...         
//products is a list that contains the data
_productsController.add(products);
...
body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _productsController.stream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {...}
```

I saw a solution proposing to periodically re-load the data from the API, for example each 1 second.

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => loadDetails());
```

Source: [Stream for API coming from PHP in Flutter (Not Firebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554659/stream-for-api-coming-from-php-in-flutter-not-firebase)

I do not think it is an efficient approach. In my app for example, I want to integrate the data changes without re-loading the data.

Is there an efficient way to make the stream reflects data changes in the app without reloading data?

Comment: Any update about it ?

Comment: @ZeffryReynando you can use a timer, but its not an efficient approach, or use socket in case its applicable, otherwise use another alternative such as firebase/firestore for realtime

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can implement your own stream with dart as shown in the [docs](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch)

With this, you will also need a delay and you will be making calls to the API periodically, but I guess that's the way to go if your API does not send any message without calling it first.

```
Stream<Product> productsStream() async* {
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    Product someProduct = getProductFromAPI();
    yield someProduct;
  }
}
```

A little explanation of the code:

- You need a loop to call the API periodically. Don't worry about infinite loops, since the stream will only be used while the `StreamBuild` that calls it is built.
- The `yield` keyword is like the `return` when using streams

Then, to use it, just implement a `StreamBuilder` calling the `Stream` you just created:

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: productsStream(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Product> snapshot) {...}
)
```

Comment: Will it work when app is death ?, means app is installed in phone but not using or running on background

Comment: @Mukta no, streams implemented this way only update while the widget is built. I'm not sure if making some changes you can make it update while running on background

Comment: @jsgalarraga what if I am calling the `Stream` in `initState` of a StatefulWidget. Will it run in background?

Comment: @jsgalarraga This was working fine for a couple of seconds(like 40-45 seconds) and updating the list, but after that circular loader comes and loader seems to load infinitely.