# Can I use streamBuilder in fetching live data from an Api

Tags: api, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Good day guys. I'm making a football score live data app in flutter. I don't know how to get around this, if I use http.get, I'll have to refresh Everytime to get the recent data. I don't know if a streamBuilder would work and how to go about it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: please try this once :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565501/8388068

Answer (score 10):

As explained in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), StreamBuilder is a:

> Widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Stream.

So, to use it, first you need to create a Stream that provides your data, pass it to the stream prop of StreamBuilder, then in the builder prop you build your widget based on the snapshot data.

Here is a short example that uses `Stream.periodic` to return the future every 5 seconds and yield the future call:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PeriodicRequester extends StatelessWidget {
  Stream<http.Response> getRandomNumberFact() async* {
    yield* Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (_) {
      return http.get("http://numbersapi.com/random/");
    }).asyncMap((event) async => await event);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<http.Response>(
      stream: getRandomNumberFact(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
          ? Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.body))
          : CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```