# Flutter timely changing image

Tags: android, ios, flutter, internet-radio

Hi I have a question regarding flutter I am building a live radio app using flutter for iOS and Android the application have 2 pages one for all shows details like timings name etc which I will get from api backend is nodejs and MySQL and one for playing audio I want live show image on the main screen and also upcoming 2 shows and pass away 2 shows at the bottom of live show image using api data which will changes time to time schedule details I am catching from api how to do that ? Is there ani plugin available or not

Answer (score 1):

The Timer.Periodic that Kozubi suggests can be used together with a StreamBuilder widget.

See the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984958/can-i-use-streambuilder-in-fetching-live-data-from-an-api).

A StreamBuilder is a good way to display changing data. The StreamBuilder listens to changes in the data and the output will be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> Timer.periodic

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:10), (var timer){
//fetch your data and update state
}
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html